# File access control mechanism in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: security, documentation

Can someone tell me where I can find detailed description about file access control mechanism used in Ubuntu 13.10 desktop.

I already tried Ubuntu documentation, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I assume what you're looking for is file permissions.  You can find a wealth of information in the Ubuntu documentation here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions